# How can I define a measure of similarity between two line segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, computational-geometry

I have two segments in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I would like to define a measure of similarity between the two segments.

My idea is that I can apply:

1. a scale transformation $s$ in order to equate the lenghts of the two segments;
2. a translation $\mathbf{t}$ in order to equate the center points of the two segments;
3. a 2D rotation of an angle $\alpha$ (described by a rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$) in order to perfectly overlap the two segments.

and then the similarity measure would be based on

1. the distance of $s$ from 1;
2. the magnitude of $t$ (i.e. $\mathbf{t}^T\mathbf{t}$);
3. the distance between $\alpha$ and 0 (or between $\mathbf{R}$ and the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}$).

but how to combine the above contributes? In a linear way?

Is there any "classic" measure of similarity already defined?

**Edit**:
The two segments are oriented so $AB$ and $BA$ are different.

Comment: I would be much easier to compute the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between the segments. If the vertices are $AB$ and $CD$, the distance is $\min(\max(|AC|,|BD|), \max(|AD|,|BC|))$.

Comment: what is the distance between $AB$ and $BA$? (it is $0$ for the Hausdorff distance, but, apparently, $\pi$ in your description).

Comment: @This: That's a great suggestion, but your formula can't be right. The Hausdorff distance between the two diagonals of a unit square is $1/\sqrt2$ but your formula gives $1$. I'd believe that it's only off by a bounded factor though.

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for noticing. I guess you found the worst case, when the formula is off by the factor of $\sqrt{2}$. uvts_cvs: I second the question by sds: are your line segments *oriented*?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. The line segments are oriented (I updated the question). Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps try the [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance), then (which I'm pretty sure is just $\max(|AC|,|BD|)$).

Comment: @sds The distance between $AB$ and $BA$ should not be zero, $\pi$ is the correct value for $\alpha$ and $\mathbf{t}=\mathbf{0}$ and $s=1$ but I do not know whether $\pi$ is the correct value for the distance.

Comment: Perhaps we could be more helpful if you added a motivation. How is this distance going to be used? Will you try to extend it to non-similar shapes? Are you going to use the underlying transformation?

Comment: @sds the motivation: I have a collection of 2D line segments and I need to do a clustering (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)

Comment: Then @Rahul's suggestion Frechet distance is your best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One measure that is sometimes used, especially if the lines get more complicated is the (normal or weak) [Fréchet distance](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.6628.pdf) (also on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance)) that takes into account the ordering of the points to be traversed on the lines. Also you may also find the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27861/similarity-measures-between-curves) useful.

Answer (score 1):

This paper describes six different measures, namely:

> Hausdorff-distance (HD), Trucco-distance (TD), Modified line segment
>   Hausdorff-distance (MHD), Modified perpendicular line segment
>   Hausdorff-distance (MPHD), Midpoint-distance (MD), Closest
>   point-distance (CD) and our new Straight line-distance function (SD).

WIRTZ, Stefan; PAULUS, Dietrich. Evaluation of established line segment distance functions. *Proceedings of the 9th Open German-Russian Workshop on Pattern Recognition and Image Understanding
Dec 1-5, 2014, Koblenz, Germany*, 89.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest methods in this PPT(https://github.com/yaodi833/traj_similarity):
[image]

And I find that TRACLUS is good for engineers

Reference: https://github.com/yaodi833/traj_similarity

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).